# I want angular 4 ng2-ui/map places-auto-complete restricted to a specific country

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary, ngui

Here is my code

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Pickup Location" places-auto-complete 
(place_changed)="pickupChanged($event)" formControlName="pickup_location" 
[types]="['geocode']" />
```

How do set options for the input type to restrict the value to a specific country(eg: uae)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `componentRestrictions` with  `[types]="['(cities)']"` which worked fine.

`<input class="search-set form-control" [(ngModel)]="placeFilter" places-auto-complete (place_changed)="placeChanged($event)" [types]="['(cities)']"                         [componentRestrictions]="{country: 'ae'}" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />`